# Bad display of markdown diff during review

Tags: feature-request

The *markdown diff* for [this *suggested edits* review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18964312) displays badly because of lots of whitespace removed in the edit. It looks like some parts on the *added* side have been removed.

[image: screenshot]

I'm afraid I have no specific idea how to handle this case better, but currently it looks strange.

Does anyone have a good idea? Horizontal scroll bars is the best I can come up with…

Comment: Looking at the rendered output, I can't think of any better way the markdown should be rendered. The formatting was really bad to begin with, and so it's logical that the rendering of the edit would also look bad.

Comment: @DavyM, I agree the original formatting was bad, but I don't think this implies the markdown diff has to look as confusing as it currently does. Just because you and I cannot think of a better way to show the diff does not mean there is none ;-) Maybe a UI expert comes by and has a brilliant idea? Is it worth posting a question at [UX Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com)? Would that be the right place?

Comment: Won't solve everyone's problem, but [SO only utilizes ~50% of my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlYLG.png) when using a widescreen monitor. Perhaps it can utilize more of the white space?